# Transform a MapView into a Button

Tags: android, android-mapview

In an Activity, I have a small Google Map and I would like when I click on it that it opens a new Activity with the map in fullscreen.

How can I transform my small map into a button ?

For those who have Foursquare on their tablet or smartphone, I would like to do the same thing than the Google Map in the Activity of a restaurant for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code setonclick listener

```
    mMap.setOnMapClickListener(mMapClickListener);
```

and than use it

```
private GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener mMapClickListener = new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {
    private LatLngInterpolator mLatLngInterpolator;

    @Override
    public void onMapClick(LatLng point) {

       //your code

    }
};
```

vote up if its helpful.